# JSON Parsing on error body (JSON Exception) org . json.JSONException: End of input at character 0

Tags: android, json, android-json

I am getting an error org . json.JSONException: End of input at character 0
This is my Code :-

```
JSONObject jObjError = new JSONObject(response.errorBody().string());
Log.e("Error","::"+jObjError.getString("error_codes"));
```

and this is my JSON

```
{
    "errors":{
        "provider":["already has an appointment scheduled at this time."]
    },
    "error_codes":["provider_unavailable"]
}
```

Can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key point here is that you're trying to get a string from an array, not directly from an object. The correct way of parsing this would be:

```
JSONObject jObjError = new JSONObject(response.errorBody().string());
JSONArray errorArray = jObjError.optJSONArray("error_codes");
for(int i = 0;i<errorArray.size;i++) {
Log.e("Error","::"+errorArray.get(i));
}
```

Comment: thanks man it worked with small modification Log.e("Error ::", ":object:" + errorArray.get(i));

Comment: no worries! i'll update the answer,  if you could please mark it as correct? :)

Answer (score 0):

If `response` is your returned JSON, you should pass it directly as parameter is it's of type `String`

```java
JSONObject jo=new JSONObject(response);
```

and then do whatever else. because your error messages are customized and returned as json string so this is interpreted as successful request with customized messages.